# how to get parameter value from query string in a page loaded by jQuery Mobile page transition

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a page, say index.html, that uses a listview of jQuery Mobile. Each item in the listview would refers to the same page (log.html), with a query string parameter appended, so the href is log.html?id=1, log.html?id=2, and the like. I am trying to get the value of "id" parameter, but does not know how. If I access that log.html directly from brower, I can get it by parsing location.search, but if the page is loaded by page transition in a listview, location.search is empty.

Comment: press f12 and go to console and read the error that is mention over there.

Comment: @user3217843 there are no errors there

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript